# JQuery - Slideshow overlaps

Tags: jquery, html, css, slideshow

I try to implement a slideshow. It works perfectly fine but while it is fading out the images overlap.

Can you tell me why?

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/7o8Lthv0/)

```
$(function(){
$('.img0 img:gt(0)').hide();
setInterval(function(){
  $('.img0 :first-child').fadeOut()
     .next('img').fadeIn()
     .end().appendTo('.img0');}, 
  3000);
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to wait for the fadeout to finish. You can make use of the callback functionality of fadeOut. See below code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $(function () {
        $('.img0 img:gt(0)').hide();
        setInterval(function () {
                $('.img0 :first-child').fadeOut("slow", function (e) {
                        $('.img0 :first-child').next('img').fadeIn().end().appendTo('.img0');
                    }
                )
            },
            3000
        );
    });
})
;
```

Comment: @greencucumber please vote, approve or comment my answer.

Answer (score 0):

I had a quick play with your JSFiddle, and since you're specifying width and height on the images anyway you can make the images absolute positioned so they sit on top of each other.

```
.img0{margin-bottom: 40px; text-align:center; float:center; margin-bottom:20px; position: relative; width: 320px; height: 240px; } .img0 img { width: 80%; height: auto; position: absolute; top: 0; left: 0; }
```

See here:

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/7o8Lthv0/4/)